# Is loading post data with ajax and having the category ID visible in the source unsafe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, security

In WordPress I am trying to use Ajax to load a few posts from category X with the click of a button.

In order to know what posts/category to load from, I have added a "data-cat" attribute to the button, as such:

```
<a href="http://url-of-category-X" data-cat="123" class="loader">Category X</a>
```

I then have a special-file.php setup that creates a `new WP_Query` to load posts from some category (whatever category ID is fed into the file).

And in Javascript I have this:

```
1- On '.loader' click use Ajax
2- get data-cat value
3- run special-file.php and feed it the data-cat value
4- get posts returned 
5- load post HTML data in the DOM 
6- End
```

And I started wondering if this is actually unsafe and open to easy hacks? Are there any big no-nos in my solution?

What made me wonder this was the thought that a hacker could edit the html using firebug or similar and change the data-cat value to something potentially malicious, although I don't know if feeding malicious category ID could really do any harm?

P.s special-file.php would look something like this:

```
$thequery = new WP_Query(  array( 'cat' => $cat_id,  'post_status' => 'publish',  'posts_per_page' => 4,  'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1 ) );

foreach post in $thequery
echo the post title
echo the featured image
end foreach  
wp_reset_postdata();
```

So all you'd feed is the category ID and it would return 4 posts using basic WordPress functions (such as the_title(); to get the post title, etc).

Comment: It depends entirely on what special-file.php does with the data-cat value. But that's not dependent so much on the source, as the server-side code in special-file.php. If, for example, there's code in special-file.php that's vulnerable to SQL injection through the data-cat value, it could be a security problem. But we'd need to see that code. Any hacker can feed anything they want into the parameters of special-file.php, regardless of the page source—you need to make sure you cope with that appropriately.

Comment: If you are using WP_Query, WordPress takes care of the necessary sanitization.

Comment: That is a good point, I have added a very quick overview of what the special-file.php will look like in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you always thoroughly sanitize the value that is posted, e.g.:

```
$cat = isset( $_POST['cat'] ) && $_POST['cat'] ? intval( $_POST['cat'] ) : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't exposing `data-cat`. What you need to be concerned with is sanitizing any request data that you get from the user. That means checking that the `data-cat` value is safe before plugging it into your database query.